# Weyl group of Parabolic subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group over an algebraically closed field. Let $P$ be a standard parabolic subgroup of $G$ and $L$ be it's Levi subgroup. Do we have that weyl group of P equals weyl group of L? For Borel subgroup, it's seems true. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the definition of the Weyl group of such a parabolic subgroup?

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg By Weyl group of $P$, we mean here $N_{P}(T) /T$ where $T$ is a common maximal torus for $P$ and $L$.